How to Implement Real-Time Live Location Tracking in Flutter Apps?
I'm developing a Flutter app that requires real-time live location tracking. My objective is to continuously track and update the user's location in real-time. However, I'm facing some issues and need guidance on how to implement this correctly.
Problem Description:
Inconsistent Location Updates: I'm using the location package to get the user's coordinates and the geolocator package for geocoding. Sometimes, the location updates are inconsistent, with significant delays or inaccuracies.
High Battery Consumption: Continuous location tracking seems to drain the battery quickly. I'm looking for ways to optimize battery usage while maintaining accurate real-time tracking.
Best Practices and Optimization: I want to ensure that I'm following best practices for real-time location tracking in Flutter. Are there specific techniques or configurations that can improve the accuracy and efficiency of location updates?

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LocationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationPageState createState() => _LocationPageState();
}

class _LocationPageState extends State<LocationPage> {
  Location location = new Location();
  late LocationData _currentPosition;
  String _currentAddress = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getLocation();
  }

  _getLocation() async {
    bool _serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;

    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = currentLocation;
        _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);
      });
    });
  }

  _getAddressFromLatLng(double? lat, double? lng) async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(lat!, lng!);

      Placemark place = placemarks[0];

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress = "${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Location Example"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (_currentPosition != null)
              Text(
                "Latitude: ${_currentPosition.latitude}, Longitude: ${_currentPosition.longitude}",
              ),
            if (_currentAddress != "")
              Text(
                "Address: $_currentAddress",
              ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _getLocation();
              },
              child: Text("Get Location"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

